# Breaking up qx/ return in Perl

Tags: perl, command-line, scripting

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.1 server which I mess around on. Currently I'm using it to monitor my internet speed and connection.

I have written a script and automated it using Perl and crontab, but now I would like to clean up my log files.

Below is what is written to the log file upon execution of the Perl script:

```
Time: 12:40:01
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from TWC (now Spectrum) (123.45.67.890)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Fibrant (Salisbury, NC) [60.95 km]: 51.184 ms
Testing download     speed................................................................................
Download: 37.76 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed....................................................................................................
Upload: 11.56 Mbit/s
```

I would instead like to have an output of:

```
Download: 37.76 Mbit/s
Upload: 11.56 Mbit/s
```

My current Perl script looks like this:

```perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) = localtime( time );
    my $nice_timestamp = sprintf( "%04d%02d%02d",   $year + 1900, $mon + 1, $mday );
    my $timer          = sprintf( "%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour,        $min,     $sec );
    my $filename = "/home/user/DailyLogs/InternetLog$nice_timestamp";

    open( my $fh, '>>', $filename ) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

    my $output = qx"/home/user/.local/bin/speedtest-cli";

    print $fh "Time: ";
    print $fh $timer;
    print $fh "\n";
    print $fh $output;
    print $fh "\n\n";

    close $fh;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the `qx` output using [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my @output = grep {/^(Up|Down)load:/} qx"/home/user/.local/bin/speedtest-cli";
print $fh $_ for @output;
```

As a side note, you can simplify your $timer code using [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html):

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my @localtime = localtime;
my $nice_timestamp = strftime('%Y%m%d',   @localtime);
my $timer          = strftime('%H:%M:%S', @localtime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Backticks (the `qx` operator) will split the output into lines if you assign the result to an array. You can use `grep` to pick the lines that you want to see

I would also use the
[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece)
module to generate your time and date strings

The code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Time::Piece;

my $now = localtime;
$now->date_separator('');
my $nice_timestamp = $now->ymd; # Generates YYYYMMDD

my $filename = "/home/user/DailyLogs/InternetLog$nice_timestamp";

open my $fh, '>>', $filename or die qq{Unable to open file "$filename" for appending: $!};

my @output = qx</home/user/.local/bin/speedtest-cli>;

my $timer = $now->hms; # Generates HH:MM:SS

print $fh "Time: $timer\n";
print $fh for grep /^(?:Down|Up)load/, @output;
print $fh "\n\n";

close $fh;
```